# Pandas not reading correct column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
    if uploaded_file:
        st.session_state.uploaded_file = uploaded_file

        try:
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(st.session_state.uploaded_file, delimiter=';')
            st.write(dataframe.head())
            st.session_state.dataframe = dataframe
        except pd.errors.ParserError:
            st.write("Feil in file reading")
```

Here is how it should be (importing csv in excel):
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK9Za.png)

Here is how it is importing using my code:
[Wrong columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWGGU.png)

Here is a snippet from my csv-file:
[csv-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcfgc.png)

I have tried encoding, names for easch columns and etc.

Comment: Can you copy & paste the header and first few rows of your csv in here? The screenshots do not provide any help. It seems as if you have more columns than header entries.

Comment: Does this help:
KasseJournalId;Tidspunkt;Hendelse;OrgenhetId;ArbeidstasjonNr;Brukernavn;Fornavn;Etternavn;KasseEkspNr;NyVerdi;ForrigeVerdi;TotalBelop;KasseOppgjorNr;BilagNr;TerminalRapportId;EventCode;KasseJournalRapportId
752789;10.10.2023 18.07.00;Bruker logget ut;2;7;as;ana;godo;;;;;;;;2;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header has 17 entries but your data has 18 entries.

If you add an additional column to your header entries you should be able to load your dataset.

For example add `;unknown` to the end of the header line.

```bash
KasseJournalId;Tidspunkt;Hendelse;OrgenhetId;ArbeidstasjonNr;Brukernavn;Fornavn;Etternavn;KasseEkspNr;NyVerdi;ForrigeVerdi;TotalBelop;KasseOppgjorNr;BilagNr;TerminalRapportId;EventCode;KasseJournalRapportId;unknown
```

**Update**

If you want load the data without a header and then assign the columns names you can do the following.

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("...", header=None)
df.columns = ["KasseJournalId", "Tidspunkt", "Hendelse", "OrgenhetId", "ArbeidstasjonNr", "Brukernavn", "Fornavn;Etternavn", "KasseEkspNr", "NyVerdi", "ForrigeVerdi", "TotalBelop", "KasseOppgjorNr", "BilagNr", "TerminalRapportId", "EventCode", "KasseJournalRapportId", "unknown"]
```

Comment: Oh thats is! 
Any way to make it read it anyway? 
Any parameters in readcsv, or somehow I can add an extra header in the readcsv line?
We get this csv-report as is, and I dont want to manually edit the csv-files.